# Having problems when comparing two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, debugging, equals, compareto

The program is supposed to translate a word from American to British version. It only works for the first word but it doesn't work for the other words because it gives the else statement instead.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BritishTranslator {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word;

        String [] america = new String[8];
        String [] british = new String[8];

        america[0] = "attic";
        america[1] = "business suit";
        america[2] = "elevator";
        america[3] = "frenc fries";
        america[4] = "ice cream";
        america[5] = "sneakers";
        america[6] = "truck";
        america[7] = "zero";

        british[0] = "loft";
        british[1] = "lounge suit";
        british[2] = "lift";
        british[3] = "chips";
        british[4] = "ice";
        british[5] = "plimsolls";
        british[6] = "lorry";
        british[7] = "nough";

        System.out.println("Please enter an American word: ");
        word = input.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < america.length; i++)

        {
            for(int j = 0; j < british.length; j++)

            {
                if (word.equals(america[i])) 

                {
                    System.out.println(america[i] + " in british is: " + british[j]);
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                else

                {
                    System.out.println("Word not found in the dictionary.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need help learning how to debug this code.

Comment: Here line word= input.nextline will take one input and on the basis of it will enter 2for loop after that it’ll check if statement if successful then this translation will be converted and block will exit else word not found in directory will be called and exit from the block again and again for loop will be called untill and unless loop condition doesn’t get failed after that we dont have any code to put any input. So first you have to change your input logic where after for loop execution it will again ask for another input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are pairing your american words to your french words, you only need to loop the arrays once and if the word equals your american word then you want to print the string at the same index in both your french array and american array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < america.length && i < british.length; i++)
{
    if (word.equals(america[i])) 
    {
        System.out.println(america[i] + " in british is: " + british[i]);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

System.out.println("Word not found in the dictionary.");
```

Comment: you're welcome @Maky. Feel free to mark this as the answer to close your question! good luck with the rest of your coding and glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

you just need to iterate over the america array, if you find the word look at the same index in the british array.
and the else out of the loop

```
    for (int i = 0; i < america.length; i++){
            if (word.equals(america[i])) {
                System.out.println(america[i] + " in british is: " + british[i]);
                System.exit(0);
            }
    }
    System.out.println("Word not found in the dictionary.");
    System.exit(0); // you dont need this as well

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the 2 arrays contain the word-translation in the same index, you don't have to iterate through the 2nd table. Just find the index of word in the 1st table and use this index to get the translation in the 2nd table. Also use a `boolean` flag `found` to check after the loop if the word is not found:

```
System.out.println("Please enter an American word: ");
word = input.nextLine();

boolean found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < america.length; i++) {
    found = word.equals(america[i]);
    if (found) {
        System.out.println(america[i] + " in british is: " + british[i]);
        break;
    }
}
if (!found)
    System.out.println("Word not found in the dictionary.");
```

With the use of `break` the loop stops as soon as the word is found.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a couple things going on here.

First, I think you don't want to do your else statement until **after** you have gone through the loop. As it is currently written, it will terminate as soon as your first 'if' statement fails due to the nature of your if/else and the System.exit(0) call.

```
System.out.println("Please enter an American word: ");
word = input.nextLine();

for (int i = 0; i < america.length; i++)

{
    for(int j = 0; j < british.length; j++)

    {
        if (word.equals(america[i])) 

        {
            System.out.println(america[i] + " in british is: " + british[j]);
            System.exit(0);
         } 
    }
}
System.out.println("Word not found in the dictionary.");
System.exit(0);
```

However, you don't actually need the second loop, since you have the index that you've found when you are iterating through your first loop, so you can further simplify your answer to.

```
System.out.println("Please enter an American word: ");
word = input.nextLine();

for (int i = 0; i < america.length; i++)

{
        if (word.equals(america[i])) 

        {
            System.out.println(america[i] + " in british is: " + british[i]);
            System.exit(0);
         } 
}
System.out.println("Word not found in the dictionary.");
System.exit(0);
```

Since the values are mapped via index, you're able to directly access the thing you wish to translate without having a second loop, making your program faster and less complex!